# Connection Refused Error When Running Spring Boot Application with Docker Compose

Tags: spring, postgresql

I'm encountering an issue when trying to run a Spring Boot application along with a PostgreSQL container using Docker Compose. The Spring Boot application is unable to connect to the PostgreSQL container, and I'm consistently getting the following error:

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgresql:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**

I am using two separate Docker Compose files, one for the Spring Boot application and another for the PostgreSQL container and I declared the containers in the same network.

In the Spring Boot application properties, I'm using the correct PostgreSQL container name in the datasource URL:

- application.properties file

  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/mydb
  spring.datasource.username=admin
  spring.datasource.password=admin
- database docker-compose file

  version: '2'
  services:

  networks:
  mynetwork:
  driver: bridge

  ## database container

  ```
  database:
    image: postgis/postgis
    container_name: postgresql
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./datadb:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  ```
- Spring docker-compose file

  version: '2'
  services:
  backend:
  build: .
  container_name: spring-application
  ports:
  - 8085:8085
  networks:
  - mynetwork
  environment:

  ```
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/mydb
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
       - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    depends on: 
       - database
  ```

  networks:
  mynetwork:
  driver: bridge

I also add this line in the pg_hba.conf file and retsart the postgresql container:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Despite these configurations, the connection is refused, and the Spring Boot application fails to start.

what I am missing? Any ideas PLEASE

possible solutions to address this issue please?

Comment: Don’t post code as image, please update the question

Comment: can you update `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb` and check

Comment: @AndreiLisa thank you for your feedback. I tried to modify the post; even if I select the entire code and apply the code formatting rule, here is the result it gives.

Comment: I see that you have 2 `docker-compose` files. Am i right ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa yes i am using 2 **docker-compose** files, for easier control and modifications

Comment: @kcsurapaneni I changed Postgresql to localhost, but it still gives the same error

Comment: Can you move it to single one ?

Comment: I have written an answer about your problem. Can you check ?

Comment: Can you push this code to GitHub? I can take a look

Answer (score 0):

As usually this kind of staff(database + back-end application) are together in the same `docker-compose` file, because `back-end` depends on `database` and it is more flexible and easy to maintain it. Also docker-compose by default set a network, more details you could find [Networking-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).
As I suggested in comments of question you should have just one single `docker-compose` file and all is going to work well.

As an example of `docker-compose` file that you can use in your case:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: "spring-application"
    build:
      context: . // Dockerfile of back-end have to be in the same context path as this compose file
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: "spring-application"
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    environment:
      - "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/mydb"
      - "SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin"
      - "SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin"
      - "SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update"
  database:
    image: postgis/postgis
    container_name: postgresql
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=admin
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./datadb:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```